# How to parse multiple similar XML tags in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file which is as follows. I want to parse this XML file using PHP.

```
<id_list>
    -
    <ids>
        <id>195002349</id>
        <id>374487611</id>
        <id>192983648</id>
        <id>168378766</id>`
        <id>161573001</id>
    </ids>

    <next_cursor>0</next_cursor>
    <previous_cursor>0</previous_cursor>
</id_list>
```

I want the output in the form:

```
Id1=195002349 Id2=374487611 Id3=192983648 Id4=168378766 Id5=161573001
```

Comment: you know, they dont make you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice for fun. Please do research before asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading the XML (with `SimpleXMLElement($file)`), use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to search for "ids", and do a `while` loop to read the element`s text.

Like so:

```
$notes = new SimpleXMLElement('test2.xml', NULL, true);
$all = array();
$results = $notes->xpath("/id_list/ids/id");
foreach($results as $to){
    echo "<br>".$to;
    $all[]=(string)$to;
}

print_r($all);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a handy little function to strip out a string between two specified pieces of text. This could be used to parse XML text, bbCode, or any other delimited code/text for that matter.

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$fullstring = "this is my [tag]dog[/tag]";
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, "[tag]", "[/tag]");

echo $parsed; // (result = dog)
```

Comment: why is that handy and how does it answer the OPs question?